# Outlook prompts for password, when not connected to VPN

Tags: exchange-server

Outlook keeps on prompting for credentials when it is not connected to VPN. It works well when connected to VPN. Please let me know how to fix this issue.
Yours efforts will be appreciated.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StrackExchange Comunity. Please keep notes that StackOverflow.com is more for Developer questions where serverfault.com is for Administrator related questions. So please the next time, use the correct community to get more and better answers to your questions ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something wrong with the Exchange/Outlook Auto Discovery Settings. Because currently it looks like if the Outlook client isn´t able to find the correct external host name for Outlook Anywhere and therefore also not the correct authentication method...

So the first step to troubleshoot that would be to use the "[Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/)" (Outlook Connectivity and/or Outlook Autodiscover test).

Based on the outcome you (or the Exchange Administrator) need to solve the errors seen in the report.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.,☺